# Weebly Embed code stopped working

Tags: html, css, weebly

I use some embed code to make a show/hide faq on our township website. However, it has all of a sudden stopped working with the latest update bluehost did to their version of weebly. Looking for any ideas, because I'm stumped.

```
<div class="paragraph">
<style>
.row { vertical-align: top; height:auto !important; }
.list {display:none; }
.show {display: none; }
.hide:target + .show {display: inline; }
.hide:target {display: none; }
.hide:target ~ .list {display:inline; }
@media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
.readarea {background-color: #AD9D7F; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;}
.underlined {text-decoration:underline;}
.italics {font-style:italic;}
</style>
<div class="row">
<a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><strong>Tax Cycle Information</strong></a>
<a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><strong>Tax Cycle Information</strong></a>
<div class="list">
<div class="readarea">
<p><strong>On Tuesdays, Feb. 7th, 14th and 21st, the Clinton Township Treasurer’s office will be open from 8:30 a.m. to 6:30 p.m. On Tuesday, Feb. 28th, the last day to pay 2016 taxes, the Treasurer’s office will be open from 8:30 to 5:00 pm.</strong></p>

<p><strong>TAX YEAR</strong><br />
<span class="underlined"><strong>Each tax cycle begins July 1 and concludes on the last day in February.</strong></span> *Exception: If the last day of February falls on a Saturday or Sunday, the last day for collection moves to the next business day.

<p><span class="underlined"><strong>Summer tax lien is July 1 and payable through September 14 without interest.</strong></span> From September 15th to September 30th a 1% late fee will be assessed. An additional 1% will be assessed the first of each month thereafter through the end of February.</p>

<p><strong>Winter tax lien is December 1 and payable through the end of the tax cycle without interest.</strong></p>

<p><strong>As of March 1, unpaid taxes are considered  delinquent</strong> (with the *Exception noted above) <strong>and must be paid to the Macomb County Treasurer's Office.</strong> The County Treasurer's Office is located in the Macomb County Administration Building at <span class="underlined">One South Main in Mount Clemens.</span> <strong>Clinton Township DOES NOT have records of payments made to the Macomb County Treasurer for delinquent taxes.</strong> You must contact the Macomb County Treasurer (586) 469-5190 to determine pay off amounts for delinquent taxes or to verify if delinquent taxes have been paid. You can also obtain delinquent property tax information on the County website: <a href="http://www.macombcountymi.gov/treasurer" target="_blank">http://www.macombcountymi.gov/treasurer.</a></p>

<p><strong>TAX BILLS</strong><br />
Tax bills should be received the first week in July and the first week of December. If you do not receive a tax bill at these times, please call the Treasurer’s Office at (586) 286-9313. <strong>Failure to receive a tax bill does not waive responsibility for making payment by the due date.</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<a href="#hide2" class="hide" id="hide2"><strong>Deferments & Exemptions</strong></a>
<a href="#show2" class="show" id="show2"><strong>Deferments & Exemptions</strong></a>
<div class="list">
<div class="readarea">
<p><strong>Contact the Treasurer's Office (586) 286-9313 for the following:</strong></p>

<p><strong>SUMMER TAX DEFERMENT</strong> is available to senior citizens (62) who meet the income requirements as well as paraplegic, quadriplegic, totally and permanently disabled, blind or eligible service persons, veterans or widows. Application must be made July 1st through September 14th.</p>

<p><strong>Contact the Assessing Department (586) 286-9468 for the following:</strong>

<p><strong>PRINCIPAL RESIDENCE EXEMPTION (P.R.E.)</strong> provides the "principal residence" of a taxpayer with an exemption from the local school operating millage, up to 18 mills. An owner must claim this exemption by filing an affidavit with the township's assessing department on or before June 1st. Taxpayers may only claim one home as their principal residence.</p>

<p>Note: A Notice of Foreclosure presented to the Assessor results in the removal of the P.R.E. status from the property.</p>

<p><strong>POVERTY EXEMPTION</strong> requests can be made by low income residents only for the current year, not for previous years. Residents must own and reside in the home for two consecutive years preceding the application and provide proof of income for all persons living in the residence. Household gross income must meet the current year's income guidelines set by the Township Board. Application can be made for the March, July or December Board of Review.</p>

<p><strong>VETERAN'S EXEMPTION</strong> from the collection of property taxes is available to disabled veterans who were discharged from the armed forces of the U.S. under honorable conditions and who own and use the real property as a homestead. An affidavit and other documentation required by PA 161 of 2013 must be filed by the veteran or non-remarried surviving spouse with the assessing office.</p>

<p><strong>RELIEF DURING ACTIVE MILITARY SERVICE</strong> can be granted to soldiers and sailors who own property. Application can be filed before or during the period of service.  Under the Soldiers & Sailors Relief Act, property can't be sold to pay delinquent property taxes during the service person's tour of active duty. If taxes are delinquent during the tour of duty, an interest of 6% per year will be charged rather than at the higher rates provided by law.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I just put it into a .html file it will work correctly in IE, Edge, and Chrome. Its just when I put it my code embed on weebly that it won't work, so I assume something in my weebly template is not playing nice, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you have used 'hide' as a class, and Weebly's default site.css Style Sheet is conflicting with your code.

SO,.. change `hide` to `custom-hide`:

```
<div class="paragraph">
<style>
.row { vertical-align: top; height:auto !important; }
.list {display:none; }
.custom-show {display: none; }
.custom-hide:target + .custom-show {display: inline; }
.custom-hide:target {display: none; }
.custom-hide:target ~ .list {display:inline; }
@media print { .custom-hide, .custom-show { display: none; } }
.readarea {background-color: #AD9D7F; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;}
.underlined {text-decoration:underline;}
.italics {font-style:italic;}
</style>
<div class="row">
<a href="#hide1" class="custom-hide" id="hide1"><strong>Tax Cycle Information</strong></a>
<a href="#show1" class="custom-show" id="show1"><strong>Tax Cycle Information</strong></a>
<div class="list">
<div class="readarea">
<p><strong>On Tuesdays, Feb. 7th, 14th and 21st, the Clinton Township Treasurer’s office will be open from 8:30 a.m. to 6:30 p.m. On Tuesday, Feb. 28th, the last day to pay 2016 taxes, the Treasurer’s office will be open from 8:30 to 5:00 pm.</strong></p>

<p><strong>TAX YEAR</strong><br />
<span class="underlined"><strong>Each tax cycle begins July 1 and concludes on the last day in February.</strong></span> *Exception: If the last day of February falls on a Saturday or Sunday, the last day for collection moves to the next business day.

<p><span class="underlined"><strong>Summer tax lien is July 1 and payable through September 14 without interest.</strong></span> From September 15th to September 30th a 1% late fee will be assessed. An additional 1% will be assessed the first of each month thereafter through the end of February.</p>

<p><strong>Winter tax lien is December 1 and payable through the end of the tax cycle without interest.</strong></p>

<p><strong>As of March 1, unpaid taxes are considered  delinquent</strong> (with the *Exception noted above) <strong>and must be paid to the Macomb County Treasurer's Office.</strong> The County Treasurer's Office is located in the Macomb County Administration Building at <span class="underlined">One South Main in Mount Clemens.</span> <strong>Clinton Township DOES NOT have records of payments made to the Macomb County Treasurer for delinquent taxes.</strong> You must contact the Macomb County Treasurer (586) 469-5190 to determine pay off amounts for delinquent taxes or to verify if delinquent taxes have been paid. You can also obtain delinquent property tax information on the County website: <a href="http://www.macombcountymi.gov/treasurer" target="_blank">http://www.macombcountymi.gov/treasurer.</a></p>

<p><strong>TAX BILLS</strong><br />
Tax bills should be received the first week in July and the first week of December. If you do not receive a tax bill at these times, please call the Treasurer’s Office at (586) 286-9313. <strong>Failure to receive a tax bill does not waive responsibility for making payment by the due date.</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<a href="#hide2" class="custom-hide" id="hide2"><strong>Deferments & Exemptions</strong></a>
<a href="#show2" class="custom-show" id="show2"><strong>Deferments & Exemptions</strong></a>
<div class="list">
<div class="readarea">
<p><strong>Contact the Treasurer's Office (586) 286-9313 for the following:</strong></p>

<p><strong>SUMMER TAX DEFERMENT</strong> is available to senior citizens (62) who meet the income requirements as well as paraplegic, quadriplegic, totally and permanently disabled, blind or eligible service persons, veterans or widows. Application must be made July 1st through September 14th.</p>

<p><strong>Contact the Assessing Department (586) 286-9468 for the following:</strong>

<p><strong>PRINCIPAL RESIDENCE EXEMPTION (P.R.E.)</strong> provides the "principal residence" of a taxpayer with an exemption from the local school operating millage, up to 18 mills. An owner must claim this exemption by filing an affidavit with the township's assessing department on or before June 1st. Taxpayers may only claim one home as their principal residence.</p>

<p>Note: A Notice of Foreclosure presented to the Assessor results in the removal of the P.R.E. status from the property.</p>

<p><strong>POVERTY EXEMPTION</strong> requests can be made by low income residents only for the current year, not for previous years. Residents must own and reside in the home for two consecutive years preceding the application and provide proof of income for all persons living in the residence. Household gross income must meet the current year's income guidelines set by the Township Board. Application can be made for the March, July or December Board of Review.</p>

<p><strong>VETERAN'S EXEMPTION</strong> from the collection of property taxes is available to disabled veterans who were discharged from the armed forces of the U.S. under honorable conditions and who own and use the real property as a homestead. An affidavit and other documentation required by PA 161 of 2013 must be filed by the veteran or non-remarried surviving spouse with the assessing office.</p>

<p><strong>RELIEF DURING ACTIVE MILITARY SERVICE</strong> can be granted to soldiers and sailors who own property. Application can be filed before or during the period of service.  Under the Soldiers & Sailors Relief Act, property can't be sold to pay delinquent property taxes during the service person's tour of active duty. If taxes are delinquent during the tour of duty, an interest of 6% per year will be charged rather than at the higher rates provided by law.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```